# Saving data into database using a form with multiple pages and one to many relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 form blade.php to get data and save into database. But I am doing a one to many relationship where there is one bear and many fish

But I don't know how to do it properly, previously I used this:

```
$bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $request->input('name_of_bear')]);
$bear->fishes()->create(['type_of_fish' => $fishType);
```

But it is only for 1 page, but what if I have 2 page, what do I need to do? Do I use associate, flash, session or something else to save the data into the database?
If possible can I also have some example for reference. Thank you

page1.blade.php:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'page1/submit']) !!}
             <div class="form-group">
                  {{Form::label('Name', 'Name of Bear ')}}
                  {{Form::text('Name', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                  {{Form::label('bear_type', 'Type of Bear ')}}
                  {{Form::text('bear_type', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
            </div>
 <div class="form-group">
                  {{Form::submit('Next', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
            </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller for page1:

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
$data = array();
$data['Name'] = $request->Name;
$data['bear_type'] = $request->bear_type;
$BearDetails = bear::create($data);
return redirect('http://test.dev/page2');
}
```

page2.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'page2/submit']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('type_of_fish','Type of fish bear eat')}}
 <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="type_of_fish[]" value="Salmon"> Salmon
 <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" name="type_of_fish[]" value="Sardine"> Sardine
</div>
                    {{ Form::label('fish_location','Where is the fish located near at?')}}
 <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="fish_location[]" value="Canyon"> Canyon
 <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" name="fish_location[]" value="Rainforest"> Rainforest
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
             {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
  </div>
```

Controller for page2:

```
$test = array();
$test['fish_location'] = $request->fish_location;
$test['type_of_fish'] = $request->type_of_fish;

$bear = bear::create($data);
$fish = fish::create($test);
$fish->user_particular()->associate($bear);
$fish->save();
return ('thank you');

}
```

bear model:

```
class bear extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public function fishs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\fish,'bear_id');
    }
}
```

fish model:

```
class fish extends Eloquent
{
        protected $fillable = array('name', 'bear_id');

    // DEFINE RELATIONSHIPS 
    public function bears() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\bear);
    }
}
```

Comment: In controller of page2 how you are using `$bear = bear::create($data);` and what is `$fish->user_particular()->associate($bear);` I can't see any `user_particular` defined in model

Comment: So sry about that, but I had already solve my problem with the use of session to send my data from page 1 to page 2